# How much does hop flavor fade during fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, hops, mash

In the end of my first batch, i thought i had put too many hop because it was 'oily' and the flavor was incredibly strong. But now in the second fermenting day the hops seems to be very distant, almost in an ideal level. So, on a scale from 0 to 10, (0 meaning complete loss of hop flavor,aroma and bitternes) and 10 meaning complete retention of hop, how far your beer will be from the ending of mash boil to the first days and even in the end of fermenting process? Thanks.

Comment: 2 days into fermentation is way too soon to draw any kind of conclusion about the beer.  Be patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hop bitterness is relatively stable, falling off over the course of many months.

Hop flavor and aroma is more volatile, falling off dramatically over the course of weeks, then more so over the course of months.

If you want bright, high hop flavor and aroma, look into "dry-hopping", where hops are added to the post-fermented beer. This is pretty much standard practice for modern, very-hop-forward IPAs and DIPAs.